# How to use Piwik Device Detector in Android project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, matomo

Lately, I have been using piwik for my app analysis, I have successfully able to track each my event. 
But, as we look into piwik DB I have found few columns like

1. 'config_browser_engine',
2. 'config_browser_name',
3. 'config_device_model'
4. 'config_device_brand',
5. 'config_device_type',

Out of which `'config_browser_name'` I'm able to track this through

```
TrackHelper.track(myTrackMeObject.set(QueryParams.USER_AGENT, DeviceHelper.getUserAgent()));
```

But getting trouble with rest of columns. To my research I have found there's a library [Device Detector](https://github.com/piwik/device-detector) which tracks all these information about device model,version,browser,type and all.

Coming to Question : **How to use this lib for android project** or If not this lib **How can I track above points through Piwik** ?

Any help will be appreciable.